# Dax - Dynamic Calculation of the Turnover remaining

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas

I actually have a table (in SQL Server) with a StartDate, a duration and a Turnover Per Month (Turnover/Duration).
[image]

Starting from the actual day.
We need to put the TurnoverPerMonth for each month, then do a Total YTD.
For example, actually we are in August, i should have :

[image]

*Actually, i auto-generated these lines in SQL Server with the table calendar (I created one line per month, so in my example i have to auto generated 5 lines in a view), then i do a TotalYTD in Power BI. But i was wondering if there are another solution easier in Dax?*

Edit :
Another sample :
[image]

If i have Two lines :
[image]
I hope that is more understandable

Comment: The question is a little unclear can you please provide more data to understand?

Comment: I have add more sample.
I would like to create a table/graph in Power BI which show the YTD Turnover.